# Sending E-mail using C# with multiple images

Tags: c#, email

I want to send an e-mail through C# code along with multiple images. When I send the e-mail without any image, then it works well but when I attach images , then content in the e-mail is not displayed .There is a template named EmailTemplate.html which contains the layout to be sent in the e-mail and the corresponding content is provided in SendMail().

Code of SendMail()

```
protected void sendMail()
    {
        string body;
        string blogTitle="Demo Title";
        string blogCategory="Demo Category";
        string blogHeadline="Demo Headline";
        DateTime blogDate = DateTime.Now;
        string registeredEmail="example@gmail.com";
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath(("~/EmailTemplate.html"))))
        {
            body = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");


            mail.From = new MailAddress("example@gmail.com");
            mail.To.Add(registeredEmail);
            mail.Subject = blogTitle;

            //code to send multiple images in mail
            AlternateView av1=AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(body,null,MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
            LinkedResource myPhoto=new LinkedResource("D:\\asp.net\\Learning Dot Net\\myPhoto.jpg");
            myPhoto.ContentId="myImage";
            av1.LinkedResources.Add(myPhoto);
            myPhoto=new LinkedResource("D:\\asp.net\\Learning Dot Net\\books.jpg");
            myPhoto.ContentId="blogImage";
            av1.LinkedResources.Add(myPhoto);
            mail.AlternateViews.Add(av1);
            //code ends

            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

            body = body.Replace("#Title", blogTitle);
            body = body.Replace("#BlogDate", blogDate.ToString());
            body = body.Replace("#BlogCategory", blogCategory);
            body = body.Replace("#BlogHeadline", blogHeadline + ".........");

            mail.Body = body;

            SmtpServer.Port = 587;
            SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("example@gmail.com", "12345678");
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
    }
```

Code for EmailTemplate.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="15" style="width:550px; margin:0 auto;border: solid 7px blue;">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" style="text-align:center">
                    <label id="title" style="color:blue;font-size:15pt;">#Title</label>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td style="width:130px;">
                    <label style="color:blue;font-size:15pt;">#BlogDate</label>
                </td>

                <td style="width:150px;">
                    <label style="color:blue;font-size:15pt;">#BlogCategory</label>
                </td>
                <td align="right">
                    <img src="cid:myImage" alt="abc" style="width:90px; height: 80px; border-radius:445px;"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">
                    <img src="cid:blogImage" alt="blogImage" width="500" height="140" />
                    </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">

                    #BlogHeadline

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <a href="ReadMoreUrl" style="text-decoration:none;" > Read More</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <a href="ReadMoreUrl" style="text-decoration:none;" > Add Comment</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <a href="ReadMoreUrl" style="text-decoration:none;" > See all comments</a> &nbsp;&nbsp; 
                    <a href="http://localhost:1847/blog.aspx" style="text-decoration:none;" > All Blogs</a> 
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <label>Reference </label> <a href="http://example.com" style="text-decoration:none;">http://example.com</a>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                <a href="UnsubscribeEmail">Unsubscribe</a><label> &nbsp; to no longer receive posts from <a href="http://example.com" style="text-decoration:none;">http://example.com</a>.</label>
                    </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The e-mail sent by this code showing #Title, #BlogDate, #BlogCategory and #BlogHeadline. In place of these, the content should be displayed as replaced in SendMail().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change position of your code. First you have to add mail content, after that you need to add email code. I have tried in my system and it's working properly.

I can't explain the actual logic of this, but its working on my system and when i check email, its showing all email content as well as images. Check below snapshot. Let me know, if you get this issue again.

```
 body = body.Replace("#Title", blogTitle);
            body = body.Replace("#BlogDate", blogDate.ToString());
            body = body.Replace("#BlogCategory", blogCategory);
            body = body.Replace("#BlogHeadline", blogHeadline + ".........");

            mail.Body = body;

AlternateView av1=AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(body,null,MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
            LinkedResource myPhoto=new LinkedResource("D:\\asp.net\\Learning Dot Net\\myPhoto.jpg");
            myPhoto.ContentId="myImage";
            av1.LinkedResources.Add(myPhoto);
            myPhoto=new LinkedResource("D:\\asp.net\\Learning Dot Net\\books.jpg");
            myPhoto.ContentId="blogImage";
            av1.LinkedResources.Add(myPhoto);
            mail.AlternateViews.Add(av1);
            //code ends

            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

[image]